# SMO some times doesn't display the instances in sql2008 cluster

Tags: sql-server, windows, cluster-computing

I have used SMO API.in that i have used SmoApplication.EnumAvailableServers(FALSE) and from that i have filtered local instances i have used this approch insted of true to make this as convinent for remote sqldiscovery also.using that api created a dll and use that dll in c++.

Now this is working in all combinations but some times it is failed to retrieve the instannces in win2008 sql2008 cluster combination. if i run the exe for 5 times it got succeed for 3 times and failed for two times...

What is wromg with win-sql2008 cluster .is there any additional changes needed to make it work properrly.My firewall is off and also added exception for tcp port 1433.

Anyy help is greately Appreciated...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

SMO finds the instances through the SQL Browser Service if I recall correctly.  The SQL Browser is listening on UDP 1434 which should be opened in the firewall, but for a cluster the service would be set to manual start up, again if I recall correctly, I don't have a SQL 2008/Windows 2008 cluster to check immediately.  Check that the SQL Browser Service is started on the nodes owning instances and then that each node has UDP 1434 open in the firewall.

Comment: in this case firewall is off then all ports are open.And ensured that sql browser is running.Still i am facing the sam problem.